# Typing props spread when using InferProps<> from prop-types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I'd like to preserve proptypes in my typescript react project (to provide runtime prop type-checking). I would only like to type props once however, so I'm using `InferProps` from `prop-types`. How do I correctly type spread props in this scenario? The compiler rightly complains here that `Property 'type' does not exist on type '{}'`. It is okay for `props.type` to be undefined in this context.

```js
const propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.any,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.string,
};

const FormikField = ({
  component: Component = Input,
  name,
  value,
  ...props
}: InferProps<typeof propTypes>): JSX.Element => {
  const [field, meta] = useField({ name, type: props.type, value });
  return (
    <Component
      error={meta.touched ? meta.error : null}
      {...field}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

FormikField.propTypes = propTypes;
```

Comment: Do you need type in the useField function? If not remove it :). 
How about adding type as optional in proptypes?

Comment: @KarlGalvez that certainly solves the immediate problem with `props.type`, and the compiler doesn't seem to care about `...props` now. Perhaps there's no need to explicitly type spread props?

Comment: Maybe? I've run into the same type of issue in projects. It seems to be a balance between type-safety and the ease/usefulness of spreading the props. For example, adding all the props and types can make maintenance a bit tedious since we have to add propTypes, but on the other hand, our components should only be using props we define. Types also helps the IDE autocomplete and the component stay true to it's interface. In your example, I think it's 'bad practice' to use props.type since it's not defined in propTypes. There may be a better way, if there is, hope you find it (and share)!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
import { FC } from 'react';

type propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.any,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.string,
};

const FormikField: FC<propTypes & PropTypes.any> = ({
  component: Component = Input,
  name,
  value,
  ...props
}: JSX.Element => {
  const [field, meta] = useField({ name, type: props.type, value });
  return (
    <Component
      error={meta.touched ? meta.error : null}
      {...field}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't think that preserves propTypes on the component, I can't then assign `propTypes` to FormikField.propTypes. The goal is to have both prop-types validation, _and_ typed component props.

Comment: @BayardRandel i've updated answer, can you check it?

Comment: You can't assign `type` to `FormikField.propTypes` either, it has to be a propTypes object.